# CJK Chinese font support in firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts, chinese

I was recently interested in Chinese philosophy research. However, I find it difficult to show ancient Chinese characters properly in my ubuntu's firefox.

The test page is https://ctext.org/font-test-page

I tried and have installed many CJK supporting fonts. I have also applied my font preference in Firefox->Preference->Language and Apperance->Fonts and Colors->Advanced. My Fonts for Simplified Chinese is set as:

- Serif: WenQuanYi Micro Hei
- Sans-Serif: Noto Sans CJK SC
- Monospace: Noto Sans Mono CJK SC

But still, the test page is not passed. This is what I saw:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can't install the HanaMinA.ttf and HanaMinB.ttf files listed on the page? Regular font sets probably don't include extended characters.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a font which can show all the unicode characters.

1. Install the Hanazono fonts shown in the test page.
2. Choose HanaMinA in the firefox's preference.

[test page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ1ob.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, random_user is correct.

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-hanazono
```